# How do I put `tax_query` in this WP_query?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

So I have a WP_Query, that displays posts from a custom post type. It only displays posts that have a date in the future, not ones that have past.

I now want to include `tax_query` in this WP_Query. So that it only displays custom posts that belong to a  specific term, in a custom taxonomy called event categories. My code doesn't seem to work since i've added the `tax_query` part. It doesn't display any messages in the browser at all. How can I make it work with the `tax_query` part added please?

```
<?php 


  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'meta_query' => array( 'key' => '_start_ts', 'value' => current_time('timestamp'), 'compare' => '>=', 'type'=>'numeric' ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => '_start_ts',
    'meta_value' => current_time('timestamp'),
    'meta_value_num' => current_time('timestamp'),
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
'tax_query' => array(
  // second array
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'event-categories',
      'field'    => 'slug', 
      'term' => $termst
    )
     // end second array
  ),

  );

  // The Query
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

  // The Loop
  while($query->have_posts()):
  $query->next_post();
  $id = $query->post->ID;
  echo '<li>';
  echo get_the_title($id);
  echo ' - '. get_post_meta($id, '_event_start_date', true);
  echo '</li>';
  endwhile;

  // Reset Post Data
  wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Where is `$termst` defined and what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment yet, but I would suggest first to modify your loop

```
<?php
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><?php the_title(); ?> - <?php get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , '_event_start_date', true ); ?></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <pre><?php print_r( $query ); ?></pre>
    <pre><?php print_r( $args ); ?></pre>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That way we can see the return from WP_Query.  It could be it didn't find any articles, could be an error, I won't know.